# Make an installer with text that is formatted (Partially Bold) in Inno Setup?

Tags: delphi, scripting, inno-setup, pascal

Anyone saw GOG.com game installer? How to make welcome text string like there including Path and Need Size in a single Caption? Where part of is bolded.

Here are examples of how changes String line breaking after modifying install path

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKbtE.jpg]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A `TLabel` cannot have formatting. Either you use several `TLabel` controls, or you use some other control (alternatively, you can use GDI to draw the text manually).

Comment: That looks like a RICHEDIT control or HTML renderer.

Answer (score 17):

You can use a [`TRichEditViewer`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm) setting the `RFTText` property and the `UseRichEdit` to True.

Try this sample

```
procedure CreateCustomPages;
var
  Page                 : TWizardPage;
  rtfHelpText          : TRichEditViewer;
  s: string;
begin
 Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Custom wizard page controls', 'Bold Demo');
 Page.Surface.Align:=alCLient;

 s:='{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang13322{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}'+
    '\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 This is a normal text, \b and this is a bold text\b0\par}';

 rtfHelpText := TRichEditViewer.Create(Page);
 rtfHelpText.Parent := Page.Surface;
 rtfHelpText.Left :=    0;
 rtfHelpText.Top := 0;
 rtfHelpText.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
 rtfHelpText.Height := Page.SurfaceHeight;
 rtfHelpText.Scrollbars := ssVertical;
 rtfHelpText.ReadOnly := True;
 rtfHelpText.UseRichEdit := True;
 rtfHelpText.RTFText := s;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  CreateCustomPages();
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Probably the OP wants BorderStyle = none on that rich edit view.. Can they do that in inno?

Comment: @WarrenP: Yes, that is no problem (`rtfHelpText.BorderStyle := bsNone`). The OP probably also wants `rtfHelpText.Color := clBtnFace`, then. (IMHO, no border but clWindow background looks horrid!)

Comment: I know about RTFViewer, but that's not exactly what i mean, coz it can't display correctly install path and if possible, part of it, if it can't fit on the line breaks to second line partially like: C:\Program<new line>Files\. But on the exammple shown top, install path fully goes to 2nd line if it is doesn't fit on a line

Comment: This question addressed to them who is skilled in Pascal Coding, and who doesn't know please do not comment about..., In inno setup is everything possible, that's why it uses pascal coding supported by Delphi..., here is what i need to get: [link](http://rghost.ru/private/36189161/541107f2df4095ec70e04e2b0e4616fd). This compiled by Russian one, but he doesn't want to give me the code.