# Option to format text in Inno Setup isl files

Tags: formatting, inno-setup

Is there an option to format text in the Inno Setup isl files?

I just want to make a single paragraph bold, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to apply simple formatting options to the Messages in the isl files. (Really, I've looked. If I somehow missed it, I'm sorry.)

Would also appreciate a confirmation if it is *not* possible so that I can stop looking and wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible. you could use [`TRichEditViewer`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm). Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9069015/937125).

Comment: Thanks. That was all I needed to know.